# YA sci-fi book where main character goes into the wrong wing of rooms

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book (I'm pretty sure it was a book) that I read in the last ten years — no guarantee on when it was published, but if I had to guess I'd go with that same time period. I'm reasonably sure it was YA, but it may not have been. I also think it was probably sci-fi, but I'm not completely sure.

The one scene I remember is that the/a main character, when trying to go back to their room (on a spaceship?) accidentally heads into the wrong wing of rooms. I think maybe the two wings were assigned by gender? However the rooms were assigned, when this character picked a room, they happened to pick their love interest's room. If I recall correctly, they were wearing said love interest's jacket at the time. Like, part of their uniform?

I have a very vague memory of this and I'm a bit worried I may be conflating stories, but I'd really appreciate it if y'all could help me find this.

Comment: "Yes, officer, I just got lost and wandered into her room, and decided to wear this cool jacket." In the brig before you can say Jack Robinson.